# How to make maven reactor recursive?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a certain problem with how maven reactor works, may be some of you could help me out.

My project structure.

ProjectA(parent of B/ aggregator of B,C)

- ----->ProjectB(parent of C & aggregator of N1...Nn)
- ----->ProjectC(parent & aggregator of M1..Mn)

When I build from ProjectA as follows:
"mvn install -pl ProjectC -am -amd",
my intention is that ProjectC (with all its dependencies direct/transitive) and all its aggregated projects (M1..Mn) will be built.

But what actually happens is that Ms fails because one of its dependencies - Ns hadn't been built.

It looks like maven reactor builds only Projects'C dependencies (-am) and tries to build all projects that depend on ProjectC (-amd) , but without building all their other dependencies first.

Is there a way to make it recursive (enforce -am on all -amd :) )

If not, what should be the workaround?

Comment: Is there a reason for using _-pl_, _-am_ and _-amd_ options instead of letting Maven build by its own?

Comment: Hi.. What do you mean by "reason". My initial intention is to build only projectC and all its submodules.

Comment: Why don't you just run mvn install?

Comment: Hi Ale..you have asked the same question twice. I have just answered you above. If you have ment running "mvn install" from projectC, that wouldn't be correct.

Comment: No, running _mvn install_ from project A

Comment: I don't want to build the whole project all the time. Just one particular module from the reactor. In reality the whole project tree is huge.

Comment: Ok, I see. The problem I see then is that one of your C dependencies, lets call it Mk depend on Ni, which haven't been build yet. Because Ns is an independent Maven module, you should build it before building C module. Did you try running _mvn install -pl Ns, ProjectC -am -amd_ from A directory?

Comment: The thing is that Ns is just one of the artifacts that should be built prior to Mk, another thing is that 0<k<n.. So it is not very practical.